# stringr::str_view() and tidyr::extract() regular expression differences?

Tags: r, tidyr, stringr, tidyverse

I'm trying to extract a column with multiple key:value pairs from a table with tidyr::extract(). I've fine-tuned my regular expression with stringr::str_view(), but I'm getting unexpected behavior - tidyr::extract() seems to match a different string than stringr::str_view().

How can I modify my use of tidyr::extract() to get the behavior I want?

example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df <- as_data_frame('protein_id "ENSP00000260585.7"; tag "basic"; tag "appris_principal"; tag "CCDS"; tag "seleno"; ccdsid "CCDS46240.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000151931.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000324484.3";')

# match I expect: 'tag "basic"; tag "appris_principal"; tag "CCDS"; tag "seleno"; '
str_view(df$value, '(tag "(?:.+?)"; +)+')

# match I get: 'tag \"seleno\"; '
(df %>% extract(value, "tags", '(tag "(?:.+?)"; +)+', remove = FALSE))$tags
```

I'd like to extract the set of 4 tag key:values to a new column called tags, which I'll then tidy some more. But that's hard when I'm just getting 1 of the 4 pairs from extract!

I think my comments above are clear, but just in case translating my regular expression to describe my intent helps, I'd paraphrase it as: I'd like to match 0 or more repeats of 'tag "(0 or more chars, lazy evaluation)";(optional space)'(greedy evaluation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah - it has to do with the greedy vs lazy take, and the fact that extract() "turns each [capture] group into a new column". So I need just a single capture group:

```
> (df %>% extract(value, "tags", '((?:tag "(?:.+?)"; +)+)', remove = FALSE))$tags

[1] "tag \"basic\"; tag \"appris_principal\"; tag \"CCDS\"; tag \"seleno\"; "
```

regular expressions...